# MySql - Join that delete duplicity in column

Tags: php, mysql, join

i am newbie in MySql. I don't know name of function (if its exist) so it's hard to find something.
I have 2 tables.

```
software
id | name
---------
1  | xxxx
2  | yyyy
```

```
software_version
id | software_id | date
----------------------------------
1  | 2           | 2013-10-9 10:20
2  | 1           | 2013-10-9 10:21
3  | 1           | 2013-10-9 10:22
4  | 2           | 2013-10-9 10:23
```

Im looking for SQL command, that join this tables, order it by date and show only unique record. For these tables will looks like:

```
id | name | date
---------------------------
4  | yyyy | 2013-10-9 10:23
3  | xxxx | 2013-10-9 10:22
```

I found something about DISRINCT but it's unuseable for this i think (i found that it looks for duplicity of whole record). Maybe something with GROUP but I really don't know. How I said in MySql I can do only basic selects, inserts etc.

Even I dont know every type of JOIN so it could be some INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN. There is so much types of JOIN but i dont see diference.

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Please post your query.

Comment: I'm a newbie when it comes to acquiring wealth. Can someone give me a fortune to get me started?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to lack a basic level of research and can add nothing to the cannon of knowledge that is SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use joins and for the most recent row for each software you can use selef join on the maxima of second table

```
select v.id,s.name,v.date from software s
join software_version v on (s.id=v.software_id)
join (select software_id ,max(date) date 
      from software_version group by software_id) v1
on(v.software_id =v1.software_id and v.date=v1.date)
order by v.date desc
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18bf0/3)

Comment: Wow, i was thinking that is some easier way, becouse of that i cant find any easy solution. So thank so much and ill try that. Thanks very much.